# KVM Qemu + Libvirt -> Debian Host+Guest => OpenGL / 3D Acceleration -> No Effect

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt, amd-graphics, opengl

Hi I use debian12 with KVM+Qemu and libvirt ( VirtManager as a GUI ) to create my virtual Machines.

I want to have several Virtual machines that have "some" GPU Acceleration

- NO Direct GPU Passthrough, as I want to use my GPU for several VMs at the same time
- Host GPU: `09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev e7)`

This are my settings in VirtManager for enabled 3D Acceleration:

```
<video>
  <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
    <acceleration accel3d="yes"/>
  </model>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>

<graphics type="spice">
  <listen type="none"/>
  <image compression="off"/>
  <gl enable="yes" rendernode="/dev/dri/by-path/pci-0000:09:00.0-render"/>
</graphics>
```

Also I have to set `<graphics type="spice"> =>  <listen type="none"/>` to `listen type`**none**
which means I cannot use the direct socket spice connection anymore to show the display of my vm. In my case I have the xrdp server running on the VM. I also installed [ThinLinc Server](https://www.cendio.com/thinlinc/download/?for-administrators) for remoting into the VM.

Testing the GPU Acceleration in the VM both with connected to xrdp server and to ThinLinc Server

(both `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE => x11`):

1.) I tried running glmark2 on the VM

- Score **with**  GPU Acceleration `glmark2 Score: 1312`
- Score **without**  GPU Acceleration `glmark2 Score: 1303`
- Scores are always the same regadrless if I use xrdp or ThinLinc or NoMachine as Remote Desktop Server all three use X11

2.) I installed UNIGINE Superposition Benchmark on the VM and I cannot run it ( crashes or stays at loading screen) when connected with xrdp or ThinLinc and also tried NoMachine Server to check if it makes a difference what remote Desktop Server you use.

My Question:

Does anyone know how to actually get shared GPU Acceleration to work ?
How can I check if it is activated on the VM?